# Copy rows from one excel file to another and allocate row.cells in the right columns

Tags: excel, vba, row, cells

I have been trying to copy a range of rows, with 4 columns each, to a new csv file. I want the cells to be allocated correctly. The files are shown below.

[image]

So, "Code", "Name", "Surname", "Number" cells need to be copied and pasted at the right cell of the new file.

- "Code" is the equivalent "ID"
- "Name" is in the 2nd column in FileA but it is in the 3d column in FileB.
- "Surname " is in the 3d column in FileA but it is in the 2nd column in FileB.

So, for example the second row from FileA will be pasted in FileB as shown:

[image]

**UPD**:
I am using this code to select the range of the rows and paste them to the new file.

```
Sub ExportRangetoFile()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
Dim xFile As Variant
Dim xFileString As String
On Error Resume Next

    lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(lRow, 1), Cells(lRow, lCol))


ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
Rng.Copy Application.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lRow, 1), Cells(lRow, lCol))

Columns("C:C").Cut: Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Set xFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Range.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

I want to change the code so to create the headers in the new file and allocate the cells of each row in the right column.

**UPD:** My problem is that my code needs a change. In the new file, I am only getting one row and not all. As a first step, something has to change here :

```
ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
Rng.Copy Application.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lRow, 1), Cells(lRow, lCol))
```

and then I will need to search how to create the headers in the new csv file.

Comment: Would just copying the lot to the new sheet and then do `Columns("C:C").Cut: Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight` work?

Comment: @eirikdaude Good help. I would like to do that by checking the header.title too. e.g. "Code" = "ID".

Comment: @eirikdaude Please check the updated version. I have used your code too and it works. Now I have to make it work in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried modifying your code a bit, and ended up with this macro which I think does what you want, while simplifying the snippet you posted quite a bit. If I misunderstood your requirements in some way, or if there is something which needs further explanation, don't hesitate to ask.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportRangetoFile()
  Dim cpFromRng As Range, cpToRng As Range
  Dim cpFromWB As Workbook, cpToWB As Workbook
  Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

  Set cpFromWB = ActiveWorkbook
  ' Set range to copy
  With cpFromWB
    lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' I assume the top left cell you want to copy from is A1, if that is wrong, change the line below back
    Set cpFromRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, lCol))
  End With
  ' Create new workbook
  Set cpToWB = Workbooks.Add
  Set cpToRng = cpToWB.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

  ' Copy everything over to the new workbook
  cpFromRng.Copy Destination:=cpToRng

  ' Shuffle columns around
  cpToWB.ActiveSheet.Columns("C:C").Cut
  cpToWB.ActiveSheet.Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

  ' Save as CSV-file
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\a245401\Range.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: It works fine. Very good structure. So, if I want to rename the column "Code" to "ID" in my new file, how is it possible? Is it worthy renaming it after creating the file (in the same vba) or allocating the cells to the right column by checking the header string? (e.g. If "Code" == "ID"). First step of my question is almost solved. Now, I am thinking of changing the code so that file "Range" accepts more row entries too without overwriting the existing ones.